# Unable to show XML data

Tags: spring, rest, jaxb

Hi my need is to show both xml and json data .
I am able to see this in local by JaxB but unable to see same code in server.
When ever I deploy that to server I got this error.
I don't know how to solve this error.
Unable to solve this, Tried a lot but Nothing happened , in local everything is fine, but when it comes to server it shows different exception.

> Error 500: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Could not instantiate JAXBContext for class [class com.rest.model.ExerciseInstructionsList]: null; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.JAXBException - with linked exception: [com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions Class has two properties of the same name "exerciseList" this problem is related to the following location: at public java.util.List com.rest.model.ExerciseInstructionsList.getExerciseList()
>    at com.rest.model.ExerciseInstructionsList this problem is related to the following location: at public java.util.List com.rest.model.ExerciseInstructionsList.exerciseList at com.rest.model.ExerciseInstructionsList ]

My Controller IS

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ExerciseController {

    @Autowired
    private ExerciseService exerciseService;


    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExerciseController.class);

    @Consumes
    @Produces
    @RequestMapping(value=OaesRestURIConstants.GET_EXERCISE_ALL,method=RequestMethod.GET,produces={"application/json"})
    public @ResponseBody List<ExerciseInstructions> getAllExercise()throws Exception{


        logger.info("Start getAllExercises.");

        System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<--------------Coming Inside List Exercise Controller----------->>>>>>>>>>>");
        List<ExerciseInstructions> listExercise = new ArrayList<ExerciseInstructions>();
        //ExerciseInstructionsList exe = new ExerciseInstructionsList();


        /*This list contains Exercise Instructions Data*/
        listExercise = exerciseService.getAllExercise();

        /*here i kept the list in     ExerciseInstructionsList    list so that i can fetch xml data also and can show the list.*/
        //exe.setExerciseList(listExercise);

        return  listExercise;
    }



    @RequestMapping(value=OaesRestURIConstants.GET_EXERCISE_XML_ALL,method=RequestMethod.GET,produces={"application/xml"})
    public @ResponseBody ExerciseInstructionsList getAllXmlExercise()throws Exception{


        logger.info("Start getAllExercises.");

        System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<--------------Coming Inside List Exercise Controller----------->>>>>>>>>>>");
        List<ExerciseInstructions> listExercise = new ArrayList<ExerciseInstructions>();
        ExerciseInstructionsList exeList = new ExerciseInstructionsList();


        /*This list contains Exercise Instructions Data*/
        listExercise = exerciseService.getAllExercise();

        /*here i kept the list in     ExerciseInstructionsList    list so that i can fetch xml data also and can show the list.*/
        exeList.setExerciseList(listExercise);

        return  exeList;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value=OaesRestURIConstants.EXERCISE_SAVE,method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ExerciseInstructions saveExercise(@RequestBody ExerciseInstructions exerciseInstructions)throws Exception{

        logger.info("Start saveExercise.");
        exerciseService.saveExercise(exerciseInstructions);


        return exerciseInstructions;
    }



//@Consumes({"application/xml","application/json"})
   // @Produces({"application/xml","application/json"})
    @RequestMapping(value=OaesRestURIConstants.GET_EXERCISE_ID,method=RequestMethod.GET,produces={"application/xml","application/json"})
    public @ResponseBody ExerciseInstructions getExerciseById(@PathVariable("id") String exerciseId ) throws Exception{

        logger.info("Start getExerciseById. ID="+exerciseId);

        ExerciseInstructions exercise = null;



         try {
             exercise = exerciseService.getExerciseById(exerciseId);

              } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
              }
        System.out.println("Coming Here>>>>>>>>>>>"+exercise);
        return exercise;
    //return exerciseService.getExerciseById(exerciseId);

    }


    @RequestMapping(value=OaesRestURIConstants.EXERCISE_DELETE,method=RequestMethod.PUT)
    public @ResponseBody ExerciseInstructions deleteById(@PathVariable("id") String exerciseId) throws Exception{

        logger.info("Start deleteExercise.");
        exerciseService.deleteExercise(exerciseId);

        return null;
    }

}
```

My Model class is :

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ExerciseInstructions {}
```

My Model List Class Is :

```
@XmlRootElement(name="exerciseInstructions")
//@XmlSeeAlso({ExerciseInstructions.class})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ExerciseInstructionsList {

    public List<ExerciseInstructions> exerciseList;

    public List<ExerciseInstructions> getExerciseList() {
        return exerciseList;
    }

    public void setExerciseList(List<ExerciseInstructions> exerciseList) {
        this.exerciseList = exerciseList;
    }


}
```

So can anyone help me in this.
I want to fetch and see both xml and json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you carefully read the error-message you see the reason: (I formatted and highlighted the message for better readability)

> IllegalAnnotationExceptions Class has **two** properties of the **same name** "**exerciseList**"
>   this problem is related to the following location: at public java.util.List com.rest.model.ExerciseInstructionsList.**getExerciseList**() at com.rest.model.ExerciseInstructionsList
>   this problem is related to the following location: at public java.util.List com.rest.model.ExerciseInstructionsList.**exerciseList** at com.rest.model.ExerciseInstructionsList

So the program complains that your class `ExerciseInstructionsList` has two properties which can be mapped to `exerciseList`, these are  `getExerciseList()` and `exerciseList`.

To fix this you can declare `exerciseList` as `private`.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="exerciseInstructions")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ExerciseInstructionsList {
    private List<ExerciseInstructions> exerciseList;

    public List<ExerciseInstructions> getExerciseList() {
        return exerciseList;
    }

    public void setExerciseList(List<ExerciseInstructions> exerciseList) {
        this.exerciseList = exerciseList;
    }
}
```

Comment: @manaskumar Please take the time and read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). _Accept the answer which is the best solution to your problem and don't add a comment to say "Thank you"_

Comment: ok I was busy in the work so I forgot  to read the terms and conditions....appreciate your help. and it worked properly also..